# mysql variables in the select

Tags: mysql

Can i use num_daysopen in the second select

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(dateopened)) AS num_daysopen,
  (28 - DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(dateopened))) as days_left
FROM table
```

The following does not seem to work, it would be more readable than the above if it did?

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(dateopened)) AS num_daysopen,
  (28 - num_daysopen) as days_left
FROM table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A column alias isn't available for use at the same level.
So add a derived table to add a level

```
SELECT
   num_daysopen,
   (28 - num_daysopen) as days_left
FROM
   (
    SELECT 
       DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(dateopened)) AS num_daysopen
    FROM 
       table
   ) T
```

See ["Problems with Column Aliases"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html) in the MySQL Docs

Comment: thanks for this, it answers the question and provides an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

```
A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is used as the
expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.
```

The alias cannot be used in `select_expr` or in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The alias set with `AS` is used as the expression's column. It can't be used as a variable, but it can be used again to reference that column.